# option tag text color not changing on mac os

Tags: html, css

Everything working fine on windows browser. But color of text not changing as per the style mentioned in `<option>` style on **any browser on MAC OS**.
Below tag generated dynamically from db.

```
<option style="color:blue" title="Firewall">(N) Firewall</option>
<option style="color:blue" title="Evidence">(Y) Evidence</option>
<option style="color:blue" title="ASVScanCustomer">(N) ASVScanCustomer</option>
<option style="color:red"  title="ASVScanCustomer">(N) ASVScanCustomer</option>
...
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: works fine for me: [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/bggdv6eu/)

Comment: Thx. hope you have checked on MAC. as i am still facing same issue.

Comment: do you have the latest version of your browsers?